# Keyword Implementation in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, new-operator, keyword

Is there a way, and how would I go about implementing my own keyword such as `in`, and `as` (etc), to be used in my code?

Here is what I had in mind. I want to (just for my own personal reasons, I guess) add a few keywords of my own, one of which would be the "`was`" keyword:

```
if(Control was Clicked)
{
   // etc etc
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No.

The closest you could get would be an extension method:

```
Control.WasClicked()
```

Comment: Yeah, I love extensino methods. But I already know how to use them. +1 though :)

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't add to the C# language, short of writing your own compiler.

However, your "was" keyword makes me think you might be looking for a way to declaratively handle events. Microsoft have a library called "[Reactive Extensions for .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx)" (Rx) that is an extension to LINQ that allows you to deal with events in a declarative fashion.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot add keywords to C# - at least not without writing a compiler for yourself. If what you want to do is simple, however, perhaps you could do it using a custom preprocessor. You would lose some syntax highlighting and error checking in Visual Studio, though.

One language for the CLR, that is designed to be extensible like that, [is Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/).

Comment: True, but you need to let him know that if he *did* implement a custom preprocessor, he's exposing himself to potential physical violence in the workplace :)